# working on sorting a linked list, written in c then outputed for kernel

Tags: c, linux, sorting, linked-list, kernel

I am working on a C program that will be converted as for linux kernel. I am inputing a linked list of people with there made up birthday information. At first I just input the information and print it out. Later when program is compiled it is suppose to print out that list as a dmesg.

I have a few issues. The first being that I am trying to input names, which I am not quite sure if i am doing correctly. I have five people each with a commented out name. I was wondering instead of writing "struct birthday *person;" if i could replace *person with *Alice or whatever name I want.

```
#include<linux/list.h>
#include<linux/init.h>
#include<linux/kernel.h>
#include<linux/module.h>
#include<linux/types.h>
#include<linux/slab.h>

#define NUM_OF_BIRTHDAYS 5

struct birthday {
    int day;
    int month;
    int year;
    struct list_head list;
};

static LIST_HEAD(birthday_list);

int simple_init(void) {
    struct birthday *ptr;
    int i;

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        struct birthday *person; //Alice
        person = kmalloc(sizeof(*person), GFP_KERNEL);
        if (Alice == NULL ){    // checks for NULL
        printf("error in person");
         }
        person->day = 9;
        person->month = 1;
        person->year = 1999;
        INIT_LIST_HEAD(&person->list);

        list_add_tail(&person->list, &birthday_list);
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        struct birthday *person; // *Bob;
        person = kmalloc(sizeof(*person), GFP_KERNEL);
    if (Bob == NULL ){              // checks for NULL
        printk("error in person");          
    }
        person->day = 8;
        person->month = 3;
        person->year = 1978;
        INIT_LIST_HEAD(&person->list);

        list_add_tail(&person->list, &birthday_list);
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        struct birthday *person; //*Mallory;
        person = kmalloc(sizeof(*person), GFP_KERNEL);
    if (Mallory == NULL ){              // checks for NULL
        printk("error in person");
    }
        person->day = 0;
        person->month = 12;
        person->year = 1958;
        INIT_LIST_HEAD(&person->list);

        list_add_tail(&person->list, &birthday_list);
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        struct birthday *person; //*Nancy;
        person = kmalloc(sizeof(*person), GFP_KERNEL);
    if (Nancy == NULL ){                // checks for NULL
        printk("error in person");
    }
        person->day = 9;
        person->month = 6;
        person->year = 2003;
        INIT_LIST_HEAD(&person->list);

        list_add_tail(&person->list, &birthday_list);

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        struct birthday *person; //*Kate;
        person = kmalloc(sizeof(*person), GFP_KERNEL);
    if (Kate == NULL ){             // checks for NULL
        printf("error in person");
    }
        person->day = 8;
        person->month = 3;
        person->year = 1978;
        INIT_LIST_HEAD(&person->list);

        list_add_tail(&person->list, &birthday_list);

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    list_for_each_entry(ptr, &birthday_list, list) {
        // print the info from the structs to the log
        printk(KERN_INFO "Birthday: Month %d day %d year %d",
    // don't know how to show name when trying to print
    //ptr->person, will this print out all names??
    ptr->person, 
    ptr->month, 
    ptr->day, 
    ptr->year);
    }
    //should print out list of people as they were inserted
    printk(KERN INFO "Loading Module\n");   
    return 0;
}
```

The next part of this C program is that I am having trouble sorting the list. I do not have any real experience in this.I would appreciate if any one had a tutorial or sorting linked list. I am trying to sort from oldest to youngest.

```
list_sort(NULL, *birthday_list, compare);

int campare(void *priv, struct list_head *a, struct list_head *b){

struct birthday *point1, *point2;

point1 = container_of(struct birthday, a); // 
point2 = container_of(struct birthday, b);

if (point1 ==  NULL || point2 == NULL) 
return 0;

if (point1->birdthday < point2->birthday)
    return -1;
else if (point1->birdthday > point2->birthday)
    return 1; 

// this should print out people from old to young
// I just copied the method I used from simple_int to print out the list. 

list_for_each_entry(ptr, &birthday_list, list) {
        // print the info from the structs to the log
        printk(KERN_INFO "Person : %d Birthday: Month %d day %d year %d",
    // don't know how to show name
    ptr->person, 
    ptr->month, 
    ptr->day, 
    ptr->year);
    }
return 0;  
}

void simple_exit(void) {
    struct birthday *ptr, *next;
    list_for_each_entry_safe(ptr, next, &birthday_list, list) { 

        list_del(&ptr->list);
        kfree(ptr);
    prt = NULL ;
    }
}

module_init(simple_init);
module_exit(simple_exit);
```

Comment: The answer for all questions - `It is up to you`. You may store name within `birthday` structure or create new structure, where `birthday` will be a member. As for sorting, lists (unlike to arrays or vectors) doesn't allow to be sorted effectively (with N*log(N) complexity). For short lists you may use any method with N^2 complexity, e.g. [bubble sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort).

Answer (score 1):

Preliminary note: It is quite weird to write a birthday information program as a kernel module.

> I was wondering instead of writing "struct birthday *person;" if i
>   could replace *person with *Alice or whatever name I want.

Of course you can, though there is little point in that, since these names are local to your `simple_init()` function and invisible outside of it. You seem to want yet another member of `struct birthday` for storing the name, e. g. `char person[8];`. By the way, the lines

```
        INIT_LIST_HEAD(&person->list);
```

in `simple_init()` are waste, because the following

```
        list_add_tail(&person->list, &birthday_list);
```

also initialize `person->list` by inserting it in `birthday_list`.

> I am having trouble sorting the list.

In the case at hand it is better to sort the list entries at the time of insertion into the list; for an example see [Linked Lists](http://www.makelinux.net/ldd3/chp-11-sect-5), function `todo_add_entry()`.